# Powershell script has to show all workstations ou in human readable format

Tags: windows, powershell, gpo

I'm trying to write a script which takes some GPO and some OU and link or unlink between them.
I am creating this in a GUI, where i have all the desired GPO on the left and the OU in the right.
problem is, I want to show the user all the Workstation OUs which can be done easily by

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -filter 'name -like "Workstations"' | ft distinguishedname
```

This is as close as I can get to making it human readable and the boss doesn't like that.
I have thought about getting the path of each workstation so it will be shown as
domain.local\office\workstations
which is as close as i can get, but i cannot find any way to the the AD object the extract the path from it.
I'm lost. Can anyone help me?

Comment: what are you  getting from that code ... and what do you want it to be? please, show a realistic sample of each. add them to your Question & wrap them in code formatting so that they are easy to read. [*grin*]

Comment: You may try the CanonicalName instead of the DistinguishedName. I'd say that's more human readable.  ;-)

Comment: Unless you have multiple domains why add the domain to a description? Just use `Split` to carve up the CN into what you need and list that in the GUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im sorry that was pretty noob of me.

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -Properties CanonicalName | Select-Object -Property CanonicalName
```

omg

Comment: Don't `Select-Object` for single property - it's actually slower than taking the default properties too: `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -Properties CanonicalName` will suffice

Comment: if i dont  select object i get some nasty results with all the ou and each one of them takes up a few lines. if i do however add select-object i get nice clean lines each one representing ou

Comment: Only add the one property then. See my answer on your other post